# Better way to store by remember mutableStateOf object in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I need to store a var which is a File. I tried these options:

```
var selectedFolder by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
var selectedFolder by remember { mutableStateOf(File()) }
```

None of them works, both give compiler exceptions. The first one gives:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Nothing?
Found:
File
```

and the second one gives:

```
Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
```

What is the correct way to store a object in a by remember var in Compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `selectedFolder` variable like this.

```
var selectedFolder by remember { mutableStateOf<File?>(null) }
```

Comment: what if I don't wanna have it nullable?

Comment: Then in that case you must provide a default value like `File("")`

Comment: well, I think it's better to do with File(".") instead of File("") but thanks